# Load html into div without changing the rest of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've seen tons of people asking how to load html into a div, and my code does that fine....but then the rest of the page changes when I load the html into the div.

I have a page a.html that looks like this, and loads b.html

a.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
}); 
</script> 



 <div id="includedContent"></div>
 <h1>This is why I rule</h1>
</head>
</html>
```

then b.html looks like this

`<p> This is my include file </p>`

What happens is a.html loads and I can see `This is why I rule` momentarily, but then the code goes out and gets b.html. When b.html loads I can ONLY see `This is my include file` and the 'This is why I rule' message disappears...

Why is this? How do I prevent it? It does this on all browsers I have tested it on.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `div` and `h1` tags are not allowed inside the `head` tag.

Comment: Get your markup out of your `<head>` element and into the body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to write your html code into a `<body> </body>`

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="includedContent"></div>
 <h1>This is why I rule</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

All your HTML markup is in the `head` section not the `body`

try this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 

<script> 
$(function() {
$("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
}); 
</script> 

</head>
<body>
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
     <h1>This is why I rule</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the body tags and it doesn't help.

Comment: Aha. It did work! My mistake. Thanks for the help. Such an easy fix!