# How to put a div in more pages

Tags: html, css

I would like to have certain divs go into more than one page for the same website just like how the stackExchange bar is one all of the pages. It would be nice to do it with css or html. I have no current theory on how to do this.

To explain my question is: **How to put certain html in all of the pages in my website without having to do it mandatory?**

All help is appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you explain more what you aim for? It is not clear what you ask.

Comment: just add the div in the page? Your question sounds so vague and basic I'm not sure if this is what you're asking. You can also use a php include if you mean to have the same element in all pages while writing it only once

Comment: Do you want to make a single page website? Then after clicking on the menu item, related page will be displayed and all other will be hidden? Have I understood right?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. I am trying to avoid server-side since I have no experience in that.

Comment: use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371888/load-html-into-div-without-changing-the-rest-of-page and then toggle the visibility of your divs with Jquery Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @computerquest try it in php (you can have a look at the answers below). You will see its really easy and afterwards you are on a new level.

Comment: I am trying to focus on one language at a time as I learn to code.

Comment: @computerquest if you like to have a look at my edited answer... best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Like to see a beginners tutorial? Just scroll down a bit!

You can do things like that with php (just as an example - if you are quite new to webdev this should be possible for you).

Lets say you have one snippet: `<nav><a href="page1">page1</a><a href="page2">page2</a></nav>`
and one snippet: `<footer>copyright by computerquest</footer>`

These snippets are consistent in your case - so they don't change on each site.
Now you just put each of these snippets into one file - lets say "nav.html" and "footer.html".

Now you create your specific sites like this:

```
<?php include "nav.html"; ?>
<div>your content page1</div>
<?php include "footer.html"; ?>
```

This page you save as page1.php and the next one as page2.php.

```
<?php include "nav.html"; ?>
<div>your content page2</div>
<?php include "footer.html"; ?>
```

The results will be as the folling code - page1:

```
<nav><a href="page1">page1</a><a href="page2">page2</a></nav>
<div>your content page1</div>
<footer>copyright by computerquest</footer>
```

and page2:

```
<nav><a href="page1">page1</a><a href="page2">page2</a></nav>
<div>your content page2</div>
<footer>copyright by computerquest</footer>
```

So this would be the result you had asked for.

NOTE: this is not THE solution but ONE (and probably one you can handle quite smart if you are new to webdev)!

hope it helps :)

---

### EDIT (TUT):

As i got to know by reading the comments the author of this question is both a newbie in javascript and PHP.

So i think **its quite important to point out some things about the different techniques!**
*BTW: This really counts only if you are also concerned about SEO and folks that have disabled js.*

Here we go...
Lets assume you have 2 different categories: "home" and "myService".

If you decide to follow the solution the link points to (from answer marked as accepted) i would be concerned about the following issue.
If you want to deliver your site like a one-site-app (so you have your "home.html" that shows up both categories home and myService) and you want to realize this by dynamically loading the content from myService into home.html (btw: really a good idea in general) with ***javascript* - anybody who don't uses javascript would not be able to access the content** of myService!

But hey: **searchengines don't use javascript - so Google (for example) would not know** about the content of myService.

*How to manage this?*

1. To handle this **you must have 2 physical sites** (home.html and myService.html) indeed. And they have to be done with complete markup including head and all the stuff. Of course its still not a big deal to load the content from one site to the other by extracting the content from the unneeded markup like `<head>`. For example something like: `jQuery('#content-container').load( "myService.html #content-container" );`. But now the advantage / **approach of don't having to rewrite the consistent parts for each site (eg footer) went by completely but from the "SEO-point of view" this would be ideal**.
2. **You must have 1 physical site but with all available contents inside.** Now that you have all your content you just hide / show the unwanted / wanted content on demand. For example something like: `jQuery('.content').hide().filter('#myservice').show()`. But on the one hand **maintaining this could be very confusing** depending on the quantity of the content and from the **"SEO-point of view" this would not be ideal because your content is less specific** now.

*CONCLUSION*

I would say: **"yepp - there are better ways!"**.
If you are new to webdevelopment i would strongly recommend to start learning a ["server-side scripting language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) (eg PHP) first and afterwards a ["client-side scripting language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) (eg javascript).

Learning the very basics of PHP is really easy and you can start learning javascript very soon too.

*THE WILDLIFE*

Here we go with a nice solution combining PHP (in a very easy way) and the javasrcipt library jQuery:

At the very beginning we first think about which elements are consistent and which are dynamic.

1. consistent: navigation bar, footer, some core markup elements
2. dynamic: site specific content

Alright so lets start with making a "template.php" (its a file that have to be saved):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- dynamic element --><title><?php echo $stitle; ?></title>
        <style>#active{font-size: 1.5em;cursor: text}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <?php # highlight active navigation dynamically: id="active"
            if     ($ssite === "home")
                echo '<a href="home.php" id="active">home</a><a href="myservice.php">service</a>';
            else
                echo '<a href="home.php">home</a><a href="myservice.php" id="active">service</a>';
            ?>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
<?php include 'template.content.php'; ?><!-- dynamic element -->
        </div>
        <footer>
            (c) by computerquest
        </footer>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.jquery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>');
            window.sSite = '<?php echo $sSite; ?>'; // "transfer" active site from php to javascript
        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now we make 2 files (1 for each site)
"home.php":

```
<?php
# set sites id
$sSite    = "home";
# set sites title
$sTitle   = "Welcome Home";
# set sites content
$sContent = 'Here we go with the dynamic site specific content of page: "home.php"...';
# include the hole template for deliviring a hole site or just the subtemplate when its requested by ajax
include isset( $_POST["sAjaxSite"] ) ? "template.content.php" : "template.php";
?>
```

"myservice.php":

```
<?php
$sSite    = "myservice";
$sTitle   = "My Service";
$sContent = 'Here we go with the dynamic site specific content of page: myservice.php"...';
include isset( $_POST["sAjaxSite"] ) ? "template.content.php" : "template.php";
?>
```

So by now we can deliver 2 specific physical sites which is **very good from points of view SEO and accessibility** but having a development environment that is **smart and easy to maintain** because if you want to make a new site the only things you have to do is make a new "file.php":

```
<?php
$sSite    = "file";
$sTitle   = "New Site";
$sContent = 'Here we go with the dynamic site specific content of page: "file.php"...';
include isset( $_POST["sAjaxSite"] ) ? "template.content.php" : "template.php";
?>
```

and also update our nav bar in template.php:

```
[...]
    <nav>
        <?php # highlight active navigation dynamically: class="active"
        if     ($sSite = "home")
            echo '<a href="home.php" id="active">Home</a><a href="myservice.php">Service</a><a href="file.php">New</a>';
        elseif ($sSite = "mySevice")
            echo '<a href="home.php">Home</a><a href="myservice.php" id="active">Service</a><a href="file.php">New</a>';
        else
            echo '<a href="home.php">Home</a><a href="myservice.php">Service</a><a href="file.php" id="active">New</a>';
        ?>
    </nav>
[...]
```

**Seems like thats all you have to know about PHP at the very beginning!**

1. **$setVariables** = "simple";
2. **$getVariables** = $setVariables;
3. **echo** $variables;
4. **include** "files-is-so-easy-in.php";
5. conditional statements **if (is_nessecary === TRUE) {**"here we go";**} else {**"let it be";**}** or **is_nessecary === TRUE ? "here we go" : "let it be";**

Thats really it in this PHP scenario except telling the server when to start parsing `<?php` and when to stop parsing `?>`...

So what do we need else? "Everybody wants a nice one-site-app" - so lets do this (the jQuery way) and make a file "main.js":

```
(function()
{
    jQuery(window).ready(function()
    {

        var aSite = ['home', 'myservice', 'file']; // the only line that have to be updated when sites structure changes

        var sSiteAct = window.sSite; // assigned on the bottom of template.php (window.sSite = '<?php echo $sSite;?>')
        // #3 navigate without leaving the current side
        var fNavigate = function(oEvent)
        {
            jClicked = jQuery(oEvent.target);
            sHref = jClicked.attr('href');
            if (sSiteAct !== sHref) // only do something if clicked element isn't that one thats currently active
            {
                jNav.filter('#active').attr('id', '');
                jClicked.attr('id', 'active');
                jContent.hide().filter('#' + sHref.substr(0, sHref.lastIndexOf('.'))).show();
                sSiteAct = sHref;
            }
        };

        // #2 append sContent (sContent is all the content containers loaded via ajax)
        var jNav = jQuery('nav a');
        var jContent = {};
        var sContent = '';
        var fInitiateNavigation = function(sContent)
        {
            jQuery('#content').append(sContent);
            jContent = jQuery('.content'); // get all content containers as so to say "jQuery DOM objects"
            jNav.click(function(oEvent)    // listen to click event
            {
                fNavigate(oEvent);
                return false;                // prevent default behavior of <a>-tags
            });
            jNav.filter('#active').click();  // trigger click event | SA "#3"
        };

        // #1 startup with loading all content containers via ajax into sContent
        var i = aSite.length;
        var iNotLoaded = i;
        while (--i !== -1)
        {
            sSite = aSite[i];
            if (sSite !== sSiteAct)
            {
                jQuery.post(sSite + '.php',
                {
                    sAjaxSite : sSite
                }).done(function(sAjaxResponse)
                {
                    sContent += sAjaxResponse;
                    if (--iNotLoaded === 0)
                    {
                        fInitiateNavigation(sContent);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (--iNotLoaded === 0)
            {
                fInitiateNavigation(sContent);
            }
        }

    })
} ).call(this);
```

Thats it! If you stay in the principles of the concept above the jQuery snippet should work always as aspected. Those principles are as simple as: the container with specific site content always have `class=".content"` and `id="filename without extension"`.

For sure the jQuery part above looks confusing when you are new to it. But thats not the point. Of course you have to learn first befor getting along with it. But if you have a close look at the PHP part you will see it is really simple.
And without too much effort you have a solid base to enhance you webdev skills.
The "client-side stuff" should be built on top of this **in my opinion**. Because this will help you to give a focus on the content itself and thats an important fact for SEO. Don't forget that search engines don't see your content like somebody who sees a client-site manipulated result.

**The more you can focus on the sites specific content the better the quality** (don't take it as a dogma but keep it mind). And thats one advantage of a templating system.

Please don't forget that i always tried to use a very simple kind of phrasing because this is targeted to beginners. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the same item on multiple pages without writing the same code over and over you could make it as a separate file and `include` it on every page you want it on with PHP. I know this isn't a HTML or CSS way of doing it but if that is what you'd like to do, it is the best way I can think of.

You might find this tutorial video on splitting up a template and using PHP to include the different items useful if you haven't used PHP before.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2JNbMpF1O4

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what framework do you use. In ASP.NET MVC I use a nice feature called Partial Views, wich is like a function. You call it whenever you want in your HTML page. If it's a static website, your only hope is to copy that div in every page. Anyway, you can't do that with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an external JavaScript file (eg "yourFile.js") which should look as follows:

```
window.yourText = 'Questo testo va nella div';
```

include this file in all your html files within the `<head>`-tag by using the `<script>`-tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourFile.js"></script>
```

and in all your html pages add this code:

```
<div><script>document.write(window.yourText);</script></div>
```

This is a easy way to not repeat your self.

Enjoy your code!