# adding different html elements to a header by using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

just started learning the fist php basics. When I have ten html files for example, all of these got a footer like this

```html
<div class="ribbon" id="footer">
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.de">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.de">Link 2</a>
    <a class="link" href="https://www.google.de">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I created a php file, took this html code into it, changed my .html file to .php and wrote

```
<?php include ("Footer.php"); ?> // Include the footer elements
```

Now I have a container called header. This header is placed on all pages but with different content. Example:

```css
.ribbon {
height: 21px;
}

#ribbon1{
background-color: red;
}

#ribbon2{
background-color: green;
}

#ribbon3{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
        <p> this is the default header </p>
        
        <div class="ribbon" id="ribbon1">
            <div>
                  <!-- The content changes on different pages -->
                  <p> different content... </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <p> this is header 1 </p>
        
        <div class="ribbon" id="ribbon2">
            <div>
                <button onclick="function1()">Btn 1</button>
                <button onclick="function2()">Btn 2</button>
                <button onclick="function3()">Btn 3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <p> this is header 2 </p>
        
        <div class="ribbon" id="ribbon3">
            <div>
                <button onclick="function4()">Btn 4</button>
                <button onclick="function5()">Btn 5</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would create another php file and write down

```
<div class="ribbon header">
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I could create a js file and create buttons dynamically. The click events get attached to these buttons and then I append these buttons to the existing header on the current page.

Is there a way to add the differnt buttons when including the "Header.php" ? Like

```
<?php include ("Header.php"); ?> // And append the different buttons to the header
```

The login page has different buttons than the profile page has. So the header content changes when loading a new URL.

Comment: When do you want other buttons to be add? what need to be triggerd to show other buttons?

Comment: when loading another page for example the login page, profile page etc.

Comment: If you load an other page those the url change?

Comment: yes, thats's what I meant sorry

Comment: My sorry I meant by example you have a page www.mysite.com and you say go to the login screen does something like this happend to your url www.mysite.com?action=login ?

Comment: hmm just started learning php, I have no idea sorry :D When logging in, I leave the page and load a new URL for example `www.mysite.com/login` to `www.mysite.com/profile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a div in more pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466343/how-to-put-a-div-in-more-pages)