# how to open a .php?id link in a div

Tags: php, jquery

i'm having problems trying to get a link to open inside my leftPan div.

the index page has a auto load function which opens a page in leftPan without a problem, and also my menu works with jQuery that way without any problems.

but i open a php page from menu from /content/ and inside that page if you click on a link it needs to open another page called moreinfo.php that is connected to the database id that is linked with the image you click on, so far so good, problem i'm having is that he doesn't open that page inside leftPan, instead he opens it in a new window and putting target leftPan results in a page that still opens his own tab/window...

this is what i am doing now without success:

```php
 echo "<a href='moreinfo.php?id=".$row['id']."'> <img src=\"content/uploads/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"219\" width=\"350\" target=\"leftPan\"/></a> <br />" . "<br />";
```

Comment: For "open" a page inside an html element you either use iframe or either use Ajax load and put the content on the html element.

Comment: For an example, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371888/load-html-into-div-without-changing-the-rest-of-page

Comment: i tried with jquery like i do with the menu and auto load but that results into php errors... 

echo "<a class="load" href='"javascript:void(0)"?id=".$row['id']."' id="moreinfo"> <img src=\"content/uploads/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"219\" width=\"350\"/></a> <br />" . "<br />";

while the load is in my jquery script which is also loaded to the page and is working perfectly with my menu

Comment: and the error is? Oo

Comment: no idea, dreamweaver only says it has errors and inside the page it just leaves me with a blank page... no errors at all though error reporting is on

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `target` should be inside `<a>` tag, not inside `<img>`

Comment: like this you mean?

echo "<a target='leftPan' href='moreinfo.php?id=".$row['id']."'> <img src=\"content/uploads/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"219\" width=\"350\"/></a> <br />" . "<br />";

that still opens it inside a new window... and tried it with target="leftPan" too but that gives me php errors

Comment: yep. show your page code. are you sure you have a frame named 'leftPan'? and what php errors do you see?

Comment: i do have an actual leftPan as that is used to autoload the home.html in and all my menu links open in my leftPan (including the php page that has the links to the moreinfo.php?id page) 

and like i said, replacing the 'leftPan with "leftPan" leaves me with php error in dreamweaver and when loading the page it leaves me with a blank page with nothing loading at all...

i can post the whole code but i have no idea how to do that here and still be readable for you.

the php page with the link is a subpage loaded in the leftPan of index.php and i guess that is the problem...