# Hebrew translation not happening while Loading HTML div into another HTML

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, translation, hebrew

so i wanted to create an html file with a menu i use in all my pages, in order to change just one html file instead of altering all pages.

i used [Load html into div without changing the rest of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371888/load-html-into-div-without-changing-the-rest-of-page) to load an  of an menu
and it worked.

but the problem was with Hebrew translation for it was jibrish/not translated.

before i separated the menu to another HTML i had no problem with language

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

on my main page the script thatch worked just fine

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#primary_nav_wrap").load("testd.html"); 
}); 
</script>
```

in body

```
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
</nav>
```

and fragment part i took of to another html (testd.html)

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="אחד.htm">אחד</a></li>
  <li><a href="שתיים.htm">שתיים</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="שתיים_וחצי.htm">שתיים_וחצי</a></li>
      <li><a href="שתיים_ורבע.htm">שתיים_ורבע</a></li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is seems that you forget to change this line

```
$("#includedContent").load("testd.html");
```

to

```
$("#primary_nav_wrap").load("testd.html");
```

On firefox it is look ok in hebrew. (also on chromium)

**Tip**:
using english in file names will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: actually i did ...sorry forgot to mention :) fixed it as in original code ))

Comment: it's still jebresh....it's like testd that has no body what so ever need an meta tag with charset=utf-8 of it's own... no idea how to do it or is this the problem. i wish i could use only english but the site i build is in hebrew :(

Comment: you see gibirsh? in what browser? try to save the file with as utf-8 or convert it to utf-8